# Set formula in multiple cells (dynamic range)

Tags: vba, excel

Im trying to put in a formula in a dynamic range. 
This is wat I got so far. What I am trying to do is, for example if in `nr(1)` says `B1`, I want the formula to start in `B3` and go to `F3`. Right now it is going all the way to `T3`.

```
Sub punt()

Dim nr(2)

For i = 34 To 58
    nr(1) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BerekeningenEind").Range("AY" & i).Value
    If nr(1) = 0 Then
        'do nothing
    Else
        Range(nr(1)).Select
        ActiveCell.Offset(RowOffset:=2, Columnoffset:=0).Activate
        For k = 1 To 5
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-5]/10*R[-" & k & "]C"
        Next k
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

I think it has something to do with `nr(1)` however I really don't know what to change. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get the `Formula` in the right cells use the code below:

```
If nr(1) = 0 Then
    'do nothing
Else
    For k = 1 To 5
        Range(nr(1)).Offset(2, k - 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-5]/10*R[-" & k & "]C"
    Next k
End If
```

**Note**: I am not sure what your `Formula` suppose to do, but I think it will need to be modified as well.

Comment: The formula is B3/10*B2, the next would be C3/10*C2, I do get the correct formula in the cells

Comment: @Milena did you test it with my code ? When I'm running my code (above), and `nr(1)` = "B1", then `Range(nr(1)).Offset(2, k - 1)` when `k = 5` equals `Range("B1").Offset(2, 4)`, which means `Range("F3")`.

Comment: I did, but I think the problem is in the line where i define 'nr(1)'. Because if I change my 'i' to '34 to 40', it works.

Comment: @Milena do you need to loop through 19 rows, and per each value of that row in column `"AY"` to run the other loop, where you place the formulas per the value of the cell `nr(1)` ?

Comment: Oh wow, you are right, that is not necessery at all. Sorry and thankyou!